# QGIS Python troubles with 'processing'

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing

I have made a script for multiple clipping raster images with a shapefile as follow:

```
##Clip Multiple Rasters with Vector=name
##Utilities=group
##RASTERS=multiple raster
##VECTOR=vector
##OUTPUT=folder

import os
import processing

lddLrs = RASTERS.split(';')
for lyr in lddLrs:
    processing.runalg('saga:clipgridwithpolygon', str(lyr),VECTOR,OUTPUT+"/clip_"+ str(os.path.basename(str(lyr))))
    processing.load(str(OUTPUT + "/clip_" + str(os.path.basename(str(lyr)))))
```

It was working perfectly, but now I am having problems with the 'processing'

The error is the following:

```
2018-09-15T10:41:39 2   Uncaught error while executing algorithm
            Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\core\GeoAlgorithm.py", line 203, in execute
                self.processAlgorithm(progress)
              File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\script\ScriptAlgorithm.py", line 378, in processAlgorithm
                exec((script), ns)
              File "<string>", line 13, in <module>
              File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\tools\general.py", line 75, in runalg
                alg = Processing.runAlgorithm(algOrName, None, *args, **kwargs)
              File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\core\Processing.py", line 252, in runAlgorithm
                processing.alghelp(algOrName)
              File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\tools\general.py", line 68, in alghelp
                print unicode(alg)
            IOError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

Any suggestion to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps an additional parameter is required which is mentioned when you run:

```
import processing
processing.alghelp('saga:clipgridwithpolygon')

ALGORITHM: Clip raster with polygon
    INPUT <ParameterRaster>
    POLYGONS <ParameterVector>
    _RESAMPLING <ParameterSelection>
    OUTPUT <OutputRaster>

_RESAMPLING(Resampling method)
    0 - Nearest Neighbour
    1 - Bilinear Interpolation
    2 - Bicubic Spline Interpolation
    3 - B-Spline Interpolation
```

---

Try including the resampling parameter into your code, e.g.:

```
processing.runalg('saga:clipgridwithpolygon', str(lyr),VECTOR,0,OUTPUT+"/clip_"+ str(os.path.basename(str(lyr))))
```